# Is the history of relations between Ukraine and Russia similar to what was between Ireland and Uk?

Tags: russia, ireland, great-britain, ukraine

Ukraine vs Russia:

- similar or same language, but cultural distance
- national resistance against imperial project, famine
- long shared history (neighbors), cultural influence

UK vs Ireland:

- native language replaced by English due to colonization, famine
- long shared history (neighbors), cultural influence

Somehow its clear that Ireland is not UK and has its own identity, but Russia believes Ukraine is Russians who believe they are not Russians?

I find the history of Ireland's resistance somewhat similar to what Ukraine is doing now - fighting for the right to have its own identity.

Comment: You might need to be careful with naming since the term "UK" originally included the whole of Ireland.

Comment: The [Kingdom of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_England) is the starting point of this development: [Tudor conquest of Ireland - Situation before the Tudors - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tudor_conquest_of_Ireland#Situation_before_the_Tudors)

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  How will you select an [Authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401)?

Comment: In history, analogies and comparations are very opinable issues because events are complex networks of interactions in very different historical context. So any "knowledge" is a simplification, and based on what you decide is relevant or not you can make two events comparable or completely different.

Comment: You already noticed some similarities. There are also some differences. So what do you want the answer to contain? Similar or not similar? This is a question of opinion.

Comment: "Who believe that they are not Russians?" is a strange question: they themselves believe.

Comment: But the main thing is even not how closely they are related to Russians. The main thing is that they do not want to live in an authoritarian state, which Russia always was and still is. For example, Taiwanese consider themselves Chinese, but they prefer a democratic state to an authoritarian one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have had national resistance against imperial project for Ireland as well. And for Scotland as well by the way.

Actually the main difference between the two situations is that the borders between Ukraine and Russia are the consequence of a merely administrative separation of authorities, in two "soviet republic" that were part of the same centralized union, and that suddendly became separated in two different political entities.

On the other hand, UK vs Ireland is the consequence of "easy to determine" borders because most of the borders is constituted by nature a.k.a the sea. The only border that is actually source of conflicts is Ireland-North Ireland border, and is the consequence of the past movements of population: In that sense it is similar to the situation of Donbass. But the difference is that North Ireland is not in Ireland, contrary to Donbass and Crimea being in Ukraine. There was not this period of administrative border that put North Ireland in Ireland, and that suddenly became a political reality with independence. The independence of Ireland, at the beginning of 20th century, only included today's Ireland and not North Ireland.

Actually, it is "funny" that the similarities between the two conflicts would actually put Ireland in the role of Ukraine and UK in the role of the Russia, **but** the conflicts are not at the same state: Donbass would be North Ireland and today, while Donbass is recognized by international community as Ukrainian, North Ireland is recognized as UK's..... So basically, if we consider only the similarities in internal situation and not other factors (historically UK doesn't "like" Russia, UK ally of USA and Russia and USA don't "like" each other...), UK should be a support of Russia and not of Ukraine.

Comment: The actual problems of today were caused (in both cases) long before the 1920's when both recieved partial independence.

Comment: ok, but north ireland is physically on the same island and logically and naturally should belong to ireland, not uk. and its called 'northern IRELAND' , still ireland, not "northern british land", just my opinion.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Could you please tell me more? Because as it is written, I disagree with your comment: the resentment between the two countries is caused by older events than 1920s, but current actual problems are caused by 1920s events and decisions

Comment: Ukrainians (and other minority nationalities) were not taken seriously as a peaple/culture/nation by the Poles or Russians before the 1920's - just as the Irish were not taken seriously by the English. The events of 1918/9 reflect this background: [West Ukrainian People's Republic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Ukrainian_People%27s_Republic). As far as the Russians are concerned, this hasn't changed.

Comment: Eventhough Poland was not an independent state at the time (pre-1920's), Polish landowners ([magnates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnates_of_Poland_and_Lithuania)) had a lot of influance that they retained until 1939. Here is also a parallel to Ireland. Who worked the land that was owned by others in Ireland and what is now Ukraine? And how were they both treated by the landowners?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't understand; your second comment actually backs up mine and doesn't back up your first one. Anyway I agree with you that the 1920s so the first modern appearence of  Irish and Ukrainian borders and thus created the problem

Comment: Allthough serfdom was abolished in Russia in 1861, the rural population (Ukrainian/Irish) were treated  as nothing more than [peasants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant#Medieval_European_peasants) that have to serve **only** the interests of the landowners and nothing more. Your answer makes no meation of this historical background **at all**, despite the fact that it is the **cause** of the problem - the symtoms of which lead to the events starting in 1918. This distain still exists today with Russia that refuses to recognise the Ukrainians as peaple, culture or nation.

Comment: What you explain there is the (part of) reason for which an Irish/Ukrainian guy does not like a UK/Russia guy. This also explains why they do not form one unified and peaceful country. This does not explain why they were/are at war. Because dislike, even hate gives conditions favourable to but does not **trigger nor justify** a war. The reason of the war is in both case a mixup of population and borders, and none country wants to let the other grab/keep the contested piece of land. The cause of the war is that one of the countries thought the conditions favourable to use military force